# How can I save multiple pages of the PDF version of an Acumatica report to a file programmatically?

Tags: acumatica

I have a report that successfully prints 1 record per page in PDF view when run manually, and exporting it as PDF is also successful.

I need to generate the report programmatically and save it to the SO record.  With the code I have, I'm only getting the first page.  How can I save all pages to the file?

```
private IEnumerable ExportReport(PXAdapter adapter, string reportID, Dictionary<String, String> parameters)
    {
        //Press save if the SO is not completed 
        if (Base.Document.Current.Completed == false)
        {
            Base.Save.Press();
        }

        PX.SM.FileInfo file = null;
        using (Report report = PXReportTools.LoadReport(reportID, null))
        {
            if (report == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to access Acumatica report writer for specified report : " + reportID);
            }

            PXReportTools.InitReportParameters(report, parameters, PXSettingProvider.Instance.Default);
            ReportNode reportNode = ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(report);
            IRenderFilter renderFilter = ReportProcessor.GetRenderer(ReportProcessor.FilterPdf);

            //Generate the PDF
            using (StreamManager streamMgr = new StreamManager())
            {
                renderFilter.Render(reportNode, null, streamMgr);
                UploadFileMaintenance graphUploadFile = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();
                file = new PX.SM.FileInfo(reportNode.ExportFileName + ".pdf", null, streamMgr.MainStream.GetBytes());
            }

            //Save the PDF to the SO; if it already exists save as a new version.
            UploadFileMaintenance graph = new UploadFileMaintenance();
            graph.SaveFile(file, FileExistsAction.CreateVersion);
            PXNoteAttribute.AttachFile(Base.Document.Cache, Base.Document.Current, file);
        }

        //Return the info on the file
        return adapter.Get();
    }
```

I have also tried generating the PDF using this code:

```
//Generate the PDF
            byte[] data = PX.Reports.Mail.Message.GenerateReport(reportNode, ReportProcessor.FilterPdf).First();
            file = new PX.SM.FileInfo(reportNode.ExportFileName + ".pdf", null, data);
```

And it appears GenerateReport is returning an IList, so I'm guessing each page is a separate list item.  What is the proper way to combine them and save as PX.SM.FileInfo?

Comment: I think the IList is for multiple combined report, otherwise sending PDF as email attachment would have similar 1 page issues but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I did test hitting Send from the manually generated report, and that file had all the pages.  Do you have any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong in my code that I'm only getting the a single page?

Comment: No clue, I posted an answer but removed it as it doesn't bring anything particularly useful. You could verify your hypothesis that generate report returns page per page by calling ToList instead of First and checking if there's more then 1 element. Besides that you can check if the report parameter are the same when called from UI than when called programmatically by displaying the parameters in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the last comment by HB_ACUMATICA, the problem lay in the parameters being passed.  I had the parameter misnamed in my code so it was coming through to the report blank.  Thank you for the point in the correct direction!